# Why isn't the new Play-Services FaceDetector available on some devices?

Tags: android, google-play-services, face-detection

### Background

Google has released a few months ago a new API to detect faces on bitmaps:

- http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2015/08/face-detection-in-google-play-services.html
- https://developers.google.com/vision/introduction#apis
- https://developers.google.com/vision/face-detection-concepts#face_orientation
- https://search-codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/face-detection#1
- https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision

It's supposed to be faster and better than the [**built-in FaceDetector class**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html), and it has no restrictions/limitations compared to it (like the need that the input bitmap will be with config 565 , bitmap width that's even, and have a max faces to detect).

The code is pretty simple, too:

manifest:

```
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
     android:value="face" />
```

java:

```
FaceDetector faceDetector = new
       FaceDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setTrackingEnabled(false)
.build();
if(!faceDetector.isOperational()){
   //show error
  return;
  }
Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(myBitmap).build();
SparseArray<Face> faces = faceDetector.detect(frame);
```

### The problem

It seems that the API isn't available on some devices, returning "false" when calling "isOperational()".

- On Nexus 4 (Android 4.4.4) and Nexus 5 (Android 6.0.1) it doesn't work at all
- On Nexus 5x (Android 6.0.1) and Galaxy S4 (Android 5.0) it works fine
- On LG G2 (Android 4.2.2) it worked only from the second run of the sample.

### What I've found

I've found some clues:

1. On Github ([**here**](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/39)), other people also found this issue.
2. The sample [**says**](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/photo-demo/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/face/photo/PhotoViewerActivity.java) (in "photo-demo", inside "PhotoViewerActivity.java" file) the library might not be available, yet that if it's not, it will be downloaded :

   ```
   if (!safeDetector.isOperational()) {
       // Note: The first time that an app using face API is installed on a device, GMS will
       // download a native library to the device in order to do detection.  Usually this
       // completes before the app is run for the first time.  But if that download has not yet
       // completed, then the above call will not detect any faces.
       //
       // isOperational() can be used to check if the required native library is currently
       // available.  The detector will automatically become operational once the library
       // download completes on device.
       Log.w(TAG, "Face detector dependencies are not yet available.");

       // Check for low storage.  If there is low storage, the native library will not be
       // downloaded, so detection will not become operational.
       IntentFilter lowstorageFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW);
       boolean hasLowStorage = registerReceiver(null, lowstorageFilter) != null;

       if (hasLowStorage) {
           Toast.makeText(this, R.string.low_storage_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           Log.w(TAG, getString(R.string.low_storage_error));
       }
   }
   ```

I tried to reset the play-services app (so that maybe the library will be forced to be re-downloaded), but it didn't seem to work (tried on Nexus 5).

### The question

1. Is there a way to force the library to be downloaded, and then start using the API? Is there a listener to this operation?
2. Would using "isOperational" trigger this download?
3. How come it's not available on some Nexus devices? Am I missing here something that I should have known about using this library?
4. Is it really without limitations/restrictions on the input, as I've found? I've noticed someone reported about memory issues ([**here**](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/53)). Would using try-catch (of OutOfMemoryError) help handling OOM ?

Comment: "it worked only on second run" -- meaning, the second `isOperational()` call returns `true`?

Comment: @CommonsWare Updated question. It's from the second run. First run returns false. Second run and later, it returns true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About why it doesn't work on some devices, [**Google answered it**](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/95#issuecomment-220163073):

> There is a known issue with the new version of GMSCore (v9) that was
>   just released today. From the release notes:
>
> - A service required by Mobile Vision is now disabled due to a serious
>     bug in that service. This will prevent users who have not already used
>     face or barcode detection from using those features. We do not
>     recommend adding new Mobile Vision features to your app until this
>     issue is fixed.
> - For apps that already use Mobile Vision features,
>     check FaceDetector.isOperational() or BarcodeDetector.isOperational()
>     to confirm detector readiness before using the face or barcode
>     detector.

Comment: This issue is tracked here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/98

Comment: @android developer, was this issue fixed by Google or what ? Issue was already closed on Github but mobile vision api still not working on tablet.

Comment: @james Maybe this can help: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/98#issuecomment-251521605

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. The workaround I did is:

- Uninstalled updates of Google Play Services
- Installed 8.7.xx version of Google Play Services from apkmirror website
- Cleared data and cache and restarted the device (Not sure if that is required)
- When I launched my app, it asked me to update google play services
- I hit update and bang.....

It is now working as expected.

PS: There are multiple variants available for Google Play Services apk. Make sure you choose correctly.